# I have hadoop 1.0.3, name node is not showing when I use jps command

Tags: bigdata

I did all steps to create the multinode hadoop 1.0.3 set up. when trying to start all services using start-all.sh, namenode is starting but when trying to give jps command. inthe list namenode is displaying. can any one help me out this issue.

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question ... but we will never know if you don't give us the steps you did.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run Name node through shell command line "hadoop-demons.sh start namenode" and check the status